# Add value of date picker in HTML text input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could someone please advise on how I could add the selected date (using a date picker) as the value of a HTML text input field? The date picker works correctly, but it currently only displays the selected date below the line:
`<div class="event-log">Event logs:<br></div>`    and not as a value inside the text input field.

Please find code below:

```
  <button type="button" class="simplepicker-btn">Select date</button>
  
    <input id="myInput" type="text"></input>
     
    <div class="event-log">Event logs:<br></div> 
    
  <script>
    let simplepicker = new SimplePicker({
      zIndex: 10
    });

 
    const $button = document.querySelector('.simplepicker-btn');
    const $eventLog = document.querySelector('.event-log');
    
    
    $button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      simplepicker.open();
    });

    // $eventLog.innerHTML += '\n\n';
    simplepicker.on('submit', (date, readableDate) => {
      $eventLog.innerHTML += readableDate + '\n';
    });

    simplepicker.on('close', (date) => {
      $eventLog.innerHTML += ''  + '\n';
    });
    
    
    var dateselected = "09/08/2022";

    document.getElementById("myInput").value = dateselected;

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the date value from the datePicker *(readableDate)* to the [**value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value) property of the input element.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput"); // <- 1) Grab the input

simplepicker.on('submit', (date, readableDate) => {
  $eventLog.innerHTML += readableDate + '\n';
  input.value = readableDate; // <- 2) Update the input value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simplepicker@2.0.4/dist/simplepicker.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="simplepicker-btn">Select date</button>
  
    <input id="myInput" type="text"></input>
     
    <div class="event-log">Event logs:<br></div> 
    
  <script>
    let simplepicker = new SimplePicker({
      zIndex: 10
    });

 
    const $button = document.querySelector('.simplepicker-btn');
    const $eventLog = document.querySelector('.event-log');
    
    
    $button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      simplepicker.open();
    });

const input = document.getElementById("myInput");

simplepicker.on('submit', (date, readableDate) => {
  $eventLog.innerHTML += readableDate + '\n';
  input.value = readableDate;
});


    simplepicker.on('close', (date) => {
      $eventLog.innerHTML += ''  + '\n';
    });
    
    
    var dateselected = "09/08/2022";

    document.getElementById("myInput").value = dateselected;

  </script>
```